# Getting errors in decoding json to swift model class

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to decode a JSON Response and getting the error every time. I also tried to make a model class from online tool but it doesn't decode it to the swift model class. When I printed the localized description it tells that The given data is not in the correct format. Below is my model class. Where as the error says

> Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue:
>   "ResponseDescription", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to
>   decode Dictionary but found a string/data instead.",
>   underlyingError: nil))

**Model Class**

```
struct ResponseLogin: Decodable{
    let Status:Bool
    let Message: String
    let ResponseDescription: ResponseDescription
    let EncryptStatus: Bool

    struct ResponseDescription: Decodable{
        let ID:Int
        let CustomerWebID: Int
        let CustomerWalletID: Int
        let CellNo: String
        let FirstName: String
        let LastName: String
        let Email: String
        let SahulatWalletCard: String
        let City: String
        let Address: String
        let ProfilePicture: String
        let TokenNo: String
        let ResponseStatus: String
        let ResponseMessage: String
    }
}
```

**JSON response**

```
{
"Status": true, 
"Message":"Login Successfully", 
"ResponseDescription":
{
"ID": 1459,
"CustomerWebID": 6275, 
"CustomerWalletID": 321123,
"CellNo": "0332334001",
"FirstName": "Haris",
"LastName": "Khan",
"Email": "myemail@gmail.com", 
"SahulatWalletCard": "3085040101018537", 
"City": "Karachi",
"RegionID": 1,
"Address": "Test1",
"ProfilePicture": "http://images/mypic.png", 
"TokenNo": "Xxxx==2121mcmvjmdx!", 
"ResponseStatus": true, 
"ResponseMessage": "Data Found"
},
"EncryptStatus": true
}

Decrypted JSON
{
  "Status": true,
  "Message": "Login Successfully",
  "ResponseDescription":"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",
"EncryptStatus": true
}
```

Any kind help can let me point my mistake in this problem.

Comment: json response in `firstName` field value is incorrect, you should add " before Haris

Comment: Rather then `print(error.localizedDescription)` print only the `error` instance. It tells you exactly what's wrong and even where. There is one wrong type in `ResponseDescription`

Comment: as Mac3n says there is a missing " in the beginning of Haris, and you should give this site a try https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: It was a typo while posting JSON, please check the updated question

Comment: Your `ResponseDescription` struct should be out of your `ResponseLogin` struct.

Comment: @Mac3n Nested structs are valid and this doesn't cause the error.

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving that particular json and not an error response in json format?

Comment: The given JSON response cannot cause the *Expected to decode Dictionary* error. Please show the **real** JSON

Comment: Yes I have checked this json and its a valid json on jsonformatter @JoakimDanielson

Comment: I didn't ask if the json was valid, I asked if the json you have posted is really the json that causes the error. Maybe you are getting a different message when the error occurs.

Comment: Your ```"ResponseStatus"``` is a Bool, but you declared it as a String.

Comment: @Starsky ResponseStatus is inside ResponseDescription, as the error shows there is some problem at the ResponseDescription.

Comment: @MujhtubaKhan How do you decrypt your ```ResponseDescription```? It looks like you didn't decrypt it correctly, that's why you get an odd string with random characters.

Answer (score 4):

**typealias Codable = Encodable & Decodable**

which conforms to both Encodable and Decodable.

```
struct MovieDetail: Codable {
    var language: String
    var genre: String
    var releaseDate: String
    var bannerImageUrl: String
}

struct Movie: Codable {
    var movieId: Int
    var name: String
    var movieDetails: MovieDetail
}
```

[For More Detail]

https://medium.com/@manojkarkie/encodable-and-decodable-in-swift-4-747328a7c7c5

Comment: It's funny, the question is not related to `Encodable` at all and both structs are not related to the JSON and model in the question at all.

Comment: Could you explain your answer and how it helps solve the issue?

Answer (score -1):

try this!

```
class Welcome: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let message: String
    let responseDescription: ResponseDescription
    let encryptStatus: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status = "Status"
        case message = "Message"
        case responseDescription = "ResponseDescription"
        case encryptStatus = "EncryptStatus"
    }

    }
   class ResponseDescription: Codable {
    let id, customerWebID, customerWalletID: Int
    let cellNo, firstName, lastName, email: String
    let sahulatWalletCard, city: String
    let regionID: Int
    let address: String
    let profilePicture: String
    let tokenNo: String
    let responseStatus: Bool
    let responseMessage: String


}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, explain the code and how it solves the issue.